# Error when calling contract method and signing it manually. SendTransaction works SendRawTransaction doesn't

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm writing a node API to expose methods on my blockchain (deployed and tested with truffle). I'm using web3.js, ethereumjs-tx, ethereum, truffle and solidity as my tech stack.

```
var txMethodData = masterKeyContract.myMethod.getData(myParams);
```

The transaction params are:

```
 const txParams = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.coinbase)),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(2000000),
    from: mainAccount,
    value: '0x00',
    to: targetContract.address,
    data: txMethodData,
    chainId: 3
};
```

im using ethereumjs-tx

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
```

Signing the transaction with the private key linked to my mainAccount

```
const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams);
tx.sign(privateKey);
const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err1, resp1) {
    if (err1) {
        console.log(err1);
    } else {
        console.log(resp1);
    }
});
```

And i get the error insufficient funds for gas * price + value. Im sending this transaction from the mainAccount (the from: field from txParams). So i logged the balance on my mainAccount

```
    web3.eth.getBalance(mainAccount, function (error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(web3.fromWei(result.toNumber(), "ether"));
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

And the result was 252.12609391539726. So it cant be without funds. I even estimated the web3.eth.estimateGas(txParams) transaction and it gave me 97899. The gas limit on the current ropstein block is 4,707,806. So i should have enough. So the question remains why im getting insufficient funds.

The only reason i suspect is that the from: field, which is my mainAccount is not actually the payer of the transaction.

**UPDATE:**
The problem might be with the signing because I just tested with

```
    web3.eth.sendTransaction(txParams, function (err1, resp1) {
    if (err1) {
        console.log(err1);
    } else {
        console.log(resp1);
    }
});
```

And it worked so the question is actually why sendRawTransaction doesn't work. Might it be related to the way I sign the transaction?

I checked that the

```
const privateKey = Buffer.from('[private_key_inserted_here]', 'hex');
```

Is actually related to my mainAccount. The private_key_inserted_here is taken from the keystore related to my main account from the "ciphertext" field. And I checked that is related to my mainAccount by matching the "address" field of the keystore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I can see

- It's `gas` and not `gasLimit`
- `chainId` is not needed
- You should really manage the `nonce` on your own instead of relying the node to send you the correct nonce. In other words, don't query it from the node but keep a variable around

If you want you can look at a minimalist wallet signer class I wrote
https://gist.github.com/gaiazov/e65a3e36c67eaf46fe81982cd193316d

Comment: I will take a look the gas instead of gas limit was indeed a mistake. Thanks for pointing it to me.